# Compile errors while building linux kernel

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel

I'm working on spinlock code in linux kernel source of 4.9.89 version.
After I've done some modification on "include/linux/spinlock.h" and "include/linux/spinlock_types.h", I build the kernel.
But some errors occurred as following:

```
./include/linux/seqlock.h:406:2: error: unknown type name ‘spinlock_t’
  spinlock_t lock;
  ^
./include/linux/seqlock.h: In function ‘write_seqlock’:
./include/linux/seqlock.h:448:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘spin_lock’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  spin_lock(&sl->lock);
  ^
./include/linux/seqlock.h: In function ‘write_sequnlock’:
./include/linux/seqlock.h:455:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘spin_unlock’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  spin_unlock(&sl->lock);
  ^
./include/linux/seqlock.h: In function ‘write_seqlock_bh’:
./include/linux/seqlock.h:460:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘spin_lock_bh’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  spin_lock_bh(&sl->lock);
  ^
./include/linux/seqlock.h: In function ‘write_sequnlock_bh’:
./include/linux/seqlock.h:467:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘spin_unlock_bh’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  spin_unlock_bh(&sl->lock);
  ^
./include/linux/seqlock.h: In function ‘write_seqlock_irq’:
./include/linux/seqlock.h:472:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘spin_lock_irq’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  spin_lock_irq(&sl->lock);
  ^
./include/linux/seqlock.h: In function ‘write_sequnlock_irq’:
./include/linux/seqlock.h:479:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘spin_unlock_irq’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  spin_unlock_irq(&sl->lock);
  ^
./include/linux/seqlock.h: In function ‘__write_seqlock_irqsave’:
./include/linux/seqlock.h:486:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘spin_lock_irqsave’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  spin_lock_irqsave(&sl->lock, flags);
  ^
./include/linux/seqlock.h: In function ‘write_sequnlock_irqrestore’:
./include/linux/seqlock.h:498:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘spin_unlock_irqrestore’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  spin_unlock_irqrestore(&sl->lock, flags);
```

I did not find anything weird in my code and I'm stuck here.
What I did in the kernel source is that I try to estimate lock holding time and lock waiting time only:

```
// function modifications
static __always_inline void spin_lock(spinlock_t *lock)
{
    struct timeval start, end;
    do_gettimeofday(&start);

    raw_spin_lock(&lock->rlock);

    do_gettimeofday(&end);
    atomic_add(&waiting_time, (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec));
    lock->holding_time = end.tv_usec;
}
static __always_inline void spin_unlock(spinlock_t *lock)
{
    struct timeval end;

    raw_spin_unlock(&lock->rlock);

    do_gettimeofday(&end);
    atomic_add(&holding_time, (end.tv_usec - lock->holding_time));
}
// macro modification
#define spin_lock_nested(lock, subclass)            \
do {                                \
    struct timeval start, end;  \
    do_gettimeofday(&start);    \
    raw_spin_lock_nested(spinlock_check(lock), subclass);   \
    do_gettimeofday(&end);  \
    atomic_add(&waiting_time, (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec));   \
    lock->holding_time = end.tv_usec;   \
} while (0)
// I added 2 atomic values to cumulate the lock time values in spinlock.h file
atomic_t waiting_time;
atomic_t holding_time;

// I added an unsigned int value (holding_time) to estimate lock holding time in spinlock struct
typedef struct spinlock {
    union {
        struct raw_spinlock rlock;

#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC
# define LOCK_PADSIZE (offsetof(struct raw_spinlock, dep_map))
        struct {
            u8 __padding[LOCK_PADSIZE];
            struct lockdep_map dep_map;
        };
#endif
    };
    unsigned int holding_time;
} spinlock_t;
```

Why did the error occur?
I'm waiting for you help.
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like one of include files, modified by you, becomes invalid. Make sure that the kernel is compilable without your modifications. (I know that compiling the whole kernel takes a long time, but you may interrupt compilation after several first files has been compiled successfully). After you modifications check **difference** between new file and old one. E.g. `diff -u <old-file> <new-file>`. Make sure that you don't change other lines than you intend. When build sources,  use `make` without `-j` option and check the very first warning or error.

Comment: Also, **defining** a variable in a **header file** is **bad**: `atomic_t waiting_time;` - this defines new variable for every source (`.c`) file, which will results in "multiple definition" error when link the kernel. In a header file you need to *declare* the variable: `extern atomic_t waiting_time;`, and define the variable in one of the source file.